# what are the differences and relations between AWS CloudFormation, SAM, CDK, and Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Just to confirm a few things:

My understanding for now: CloudFormation is a standard to use templates to describe cloud infrastructure.

SAM vs Terraform: SAM is a tool to ask CloudFormation to run the templates and manage the resource instances described by the templates. Terraform is another tool with similar purposes, which can also be used on other clouds rather than AWS.

CDK vs SAM: I guess, CDK is based on SAM/CloudFormation. While SAM provides a CLI to build cloud resources, CDK provides a programable approach to do the same thing.

These are my guesses. I will really appreciate it if anyone can help me better understand the concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is pretty close to these tools definition and the their purposes.
But it good to know that in CDK the resource doesn't create directly, after your code run they actually creating CloudFormation template to start building resources in AWS.